# Is this the correct way to convert a UTC datetime string into localtime?

Tags: python, time

Is this the correct way to convert a UTC string into local time allowing for daylight savings? It looks ok to me but you never know :)

```
import time
UTC_STRING = "2010-03-25 02:00:00"
stamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(UTC_STRING,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
stamp -= time.timezone
now   = time.localtime()
if now[8] == 1:
    stamp += 60*60
elif now[8] == -1:
    stamp -= 60*60
print 'UTC: ', time.gmtime(stamp)
print 'Local: ', time.localtime(stamp)
```

--- Results from New Zealand (GMT+12 dst=1) ---

```
UTC:  (2010, 3, 25, 2, 0, 0, 3, 84, 0)
Local:  (2010, 3, 25, 15, 0, 0, 3, 84, 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

timezone related calculations are not trivial and there are already good libraries available e.g. use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), using that you will be able to convert from any timezone to any other timezone with confidence. usage is as simple as this

```
>>> warsaw = pytz.timezone('Europe/Warsaw')
>>> loc_dt1 = warsaw.localize(datetime(1915, 8, 4, 23, 59, 59), is_dst=False)
```

Comment: I would like to hang a poster where I work reading "clock programming is not trivial!"

Comment: I have tested using pytz. The only problem I see is that you need to know the standard timezone string in order to set the timezone. However when running across multiple O/S's especially including Windows (which has to have the strangest way of defining the timezone), and after several hours of testing, this code snipit was the only one I could get to work consistently across platforms.

Comment: but these are standard string and there need to be way to tell which timezone